# Query data from postgresql functions not working in app, but works when testing manually

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I met an annoyance when trying to use simple function to query data for my web app. The idea is to use one function to list the contents of one table; the other function to use the `user-selected record_id` in this table to query the detailed contents data in another table.

When running, the app ran the two functions without any error while no data got. Checked the console and found the second function query results is `null` (I `console.log` the input for the second function, found they got and  using the correct query keys). Since I am sure database has the data for query.

I tried:

1. use `psql` command line to query data using the same query keys, I have the results without problem;
2. I run a node command line, and try to run the two functions by providing the query keys, it also gave me the correct results.

So the functions should work. Now my question is why put them in the app and let them run by themselves, they did not get the query results?

I am using `pg = require("pg")`; and `const pool = new pg.Pool(config)` for database connection;

Your sharing of your experience will be very appreciated.

(UPDATE)The functions are like below:

```
function listItemDB(callback){

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
  }

  //use the client for executing the query
  client.query(`SELECT * FROM basicdb.items`,  
                function(err, result) {
                    //call `done(err)` to release the client back to the pool (or destroy it if there is an error)
                    done(err);

                    if(err) {
                      return console.error('error running query', err);
                    }
                    // console.log(result.rows);
                    callback(result.rows);
  });
});
```

}

The above function is only trying to get "item1" and "dataset1" for future use and pass them to below function args. It does its job perfectly.

```
function getFileName(itemName,datasetName, callback) {

let fileName;

console.log(itemName,datasetName);

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    if(err) {
      return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    }

    client.query("SELECT * "+
                 "FROM basicdb.dataset "+
                 "INNER JOIN basicdb.items "+
                 "ON basicdb.dataset.item_id = basicdb.items.item_id "+ 
                 "WHERE (basicdb.items.item_name = ($1)) "+
                   "AND (basicdb.dataset.datasetname = ($2))",[itemName,datasetName],

                   function (err, result){
                      done();
                      if(err) {
                          return console.error('error running query', err);
                      }
                      let records = result.rows;
                      fileName = records[records.length-1].filename;
                      callback(fileName); 
                    });
});
```

}

This above function is trying to get the filename so the main app can use it. The code to call the above function in my main app.js is like below:

```
    db.getFileName("item1","dataset1",function(fileName) {
//do something with the fileName....}
```

("db" is the module name which include the functions.)

Comment: Please show the relevant parts of your code. Most probably you are not chaining the asynchronous calls correctly, but this is juste wild speculation without any code...

Comment: @Robin you need to publish the code that you execute, not just the library initialization.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527940/jcaron,@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102051/vitaly-t, just tried to paste the related codes.  Could you please share your experience. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem, which is a low-level mistake and has nothing to do with the database and the queries.
The item names got from the dropdown list in the app, which was feed to the function args, has one " "(space) attached to the end of the name(i dont know why?), which always "!=" the record in the database:-(, so always no query result in the app. But for the function test, I hardcode the item name which is correct "==" the record in the database. Since it is " ", even when I console.log(itemName), I did not find the space at the end.

It turns out to be 'A mistake of space'.